# Tabindex target the div (FireFox issue)

Tags: firefox, tabindex

I'm not sure if this is a Firefox (Chrome doesn't do that) issue only but for some reason in this [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/m0nxe7gq/) the pink line is targeted by Tabindex.

I know I can simply add Tabindex=-1 to avoid that behavior but I'm not sure if this is a Firefox BUG or I don't know something about Tabindex.

Firefox basically targets with Tabindex a Div which has Overflow: auto or hidden (only clip isn't affected) and has smaller height than the inside Div

Is it a BUG or something is hidden between the lines?

```
<Input type="text" value="first input">
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 9px">
  <div style="padding-top: 10px; background-color: pink"></div>
</div>
<Input type="text" value="second input">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an old bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1069739

Having the overflow parent element with a child element that has height seems to trigger it in this case. If you remove the `overflow: auto` or just make that element pink and remove the child, it seems to fix the issue.

Edit:
Could be a by-product of enforcing scrollable elements to be recognized as focusable elements per the standards, but that's just a guess.

Edit2:
Actually, in this case I don't think it's a bug. With `overflow: auto;` it would be perceived as a scrollable element and *should* be tabbable for accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for guesses. Scrollable element is nice point but with overflow: hidden doesn't make sense ;). At least Chrome and Edge are not affected by this issue. Firefox knows probably more ;)